# Application restart is required when user accepts READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

When user accepts `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, the permission is granted successfully (it can be seen in debug). But the directory can't be read (`dir.canRead()` is `false` in debug) until the app is restarted.

```
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 28
```

What is wrong with Android Pie?

P.S. I'm absolutely sure that my code is written right (this part of asking for permission etc.)

Comment: Please provide more code to help us debug the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, but with the official release on Pixels it has been solved, so the bug was happening only on emulators (probably due to the fact that they have still a beta image)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clue! It works correctly on real device, you are right. Thanks!!!